# Array Size Not Defined? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, size

Dumb question. but can you do this.
(these are global variables by the way)

```
int size;
double Values[size];
```

If Im getting the SIZE from a file?

I know you probably can't, but maybe theirs some way to readjust the size based on the number I read in from the file (like say I read in 7, I know Values will have to be of Size 7).

The compiler complains, but Im wondering if their is some workaround. (these have to stay as global variables btw.

Comment: @Helper:  Nothing ever *needs* to be a global.  Well, "nothing ever" is a bit strong, but you get my point.

Comment: @John This was more of an ironic question. Sadly, it's hard to embed irony in textual form :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can only specify array sizes like this using constant integral expressions.  Meaning known at compile-time.

You probably shouldn't be doing this, anyway.  Instead, you should be using a vector.

If for whatever reason you can't use a vector (which I would seriously doubt), then your next option would be to use dynamically-allocated arrays.  But please, for the love of all that is good int he world, use a smart pointer if you do this.

Comment: You can also use the non-standard but apparently extremely common alloca() for stack-based dynamic arrays.

Comment: Ya I was going to use a vector....but for some reason I can't find for the world of me how to read just a single line into a vector. When i know how long the vector needs to be (after I read in the first value)

Comment: @Mercfh:  Post a seperate question about that.  I estimate you get an answer within 42 seconds.  Maybe even from me.

Comment: Will do, i've been asking tons of questions today so I always feel bad when I have to ask another.....but I guess it's just one of those days.

Comment: Asking questions is what this site is all about ;-)

Comment: @Eiko I know, I've literally been going from question to question today. I'll get one solved, but that presents another problem. Like I said one of those days

Answer (score 3):

**You can**, actually :)

**C99** allows that. MSVC doesn't support C99, GCC does.

**C++** compilers also tend to allow that **as an extension** (answer yourself if you're OK with depending on compiler extensions). The only requirement is that you need to know `size` at the moment of declaration of `Values`.

A `std::vector` is usually better (and safer and standarised and so on) anyway, unless you really *really* want that data on the stack.

Comment: Does C99 really support **global** variable-length arrays?

Comment: I mentioned `size` being known at the moment of declaration, so for global arrays it would reduce to "known at compile time", imho - unless I've got something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it if you allocate them dynamically:

```
double *Values = new double[size];
...

delete [] Values;
```

but not statically.

Comment: How....would I go about doing that? Allocating them dynamically.  Like lets say I say Size=10, can I just change the size later on in the program after I read in the number from the file

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit about global variables. Don't do the `new` where you declare Values (so `double *Values;`), then set it wherever you read the size from the file (i.e. `Values = new double[size];`).